# Serialized object to mysql database in R

Tags: mysql, r, serialization, rmysql

If I have serialized data like:

```
> a <- 1:5 
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> b <- serialize(a,NULL)
> b
[1] 58 0a 00 00 00 02 00 02 0f 02 00 02 03 00 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05
> b[1]
[1] 58
> b[8]
[1] 02
```

How can I put that serialized data into a MySQL table? I have other info there also. I read that it can be done as blob, but I don't know how it works. I am using RMySQL. I have tried:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO table(",b," info, moreInfo, otherStuff, more, date )")
```

but it won't work.

If I use

```
query <- paste ("INSERT INTO table(",b," info, moreInfo, otherStuff, more, date )")
dbGetQuery(con,query)
```

it still won't work.

Comment: I think you may need to use `dbWriteTable`.

Comment: I alredy have table where I want to insert the data.

Comment: Yes, I imagine you do. You typically do inserts by specifying `append = TRUE` in `dbWriteTable`.

Comment: There are more than a few things wrong with how you are going about this. Before you try inserting serialized data into a table, try figuring out how to insert a typical value into a table in SQL. I think you are missing a comma before `info` in your query, but even that wouldn't make sense.. you would need a `VALUES` statement after that to actually put stuff in. Also, instead of saying "it won't work", try telling us the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
library(RODBC)
dt=data.table(a=sample(10),b=sample(10)*10)
sqlSave(con, dt, tablename='sampletablename') # overwrites existing sampletablename table
sqlSave(con, dt, tablename='sampletablename', append=TRUE) # append instead of overwrite
```

Comment: But is it possible to put that serialized data to mysql as one object. so that on every row there will be one serialized data with other stuff also